# C program not seeing snprintf after including stdio

Tags: c, stdio

I have file `command.c`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

#define MAXLEN 1000

/* write_message: if argument != NULL, write argument to group, else open group in vim
 * returns 0 on success
 * returns -1 on failure
 */
int write_message(char *message, char *path, char *group) {
    char *editor, sys_call[MAXLEN];

    editor = "vim";

    if (message == NULL) {
        snprintf(sys_call, MAXLEN, "%s %s%s.txt", editor, path, group);
        printf("sys_call = %s\n", sys_call);
        /*        return system(sys_call);*/
    }

    return 0;
}
```

when I compile with `gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c89 -c command.c` I get the error message:

```
command.c: In function ‘write_message’:
command.c:16:9: error: implicit declaration of function ‘snprintf’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   16 |         snprintf(sys_call, MAXLEN, "%s %s%s.txt", editor, path, group);
      |         ^~~~~~~~
command.c:2:1: note: ‘snprintf’ is defined in header ‘<stdio.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <stdio.h>’?
    1 | #include <stdlib.h>
  +++ |+#include <stdio.h>
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

I can not use `snprintf` because it is not defined even though I have included `stdio`.

Comment: What version of gcc?  Is this this the entire output of gcc?

Comment: Can't you at least use `gcc -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -g -c command.c` ? Since C89 is about 31 years old. Consider using C11 defined in [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). See documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/)

Answer (score 4):

The `snprintf` function is not defined by the the C89 standard, it was only introduced later by C99. Since you are explicitly compiling with `-std=c89`, GCC will not provide you with such function.

You have different options:

1. Compile with (at least) `-std=c99`.
2. Use the appropriate feature test macros documented in [`man 3 snprintf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html), for example adding `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` *at the very beginning* of your `.c` file (before any `#include`).
3. Create your own `snprintf()` function.
4. Declare `snprintf` with the appropriate signature (as shown in [`man 3 snprintf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html)) and use it anyway since GCC will automatically dynamically link glibc, then pray that the function will be available at runtime. Ok, seriously, **do not do this** for any reason other than having fun.

---

PS: you can find a list of new features introduced in C99 [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). Among those:

> - new library functions, such as snprintf

Comment: There might be gcc/glibc-specific ways to enable its use even with C89, as a non-standard library function.  Time to dig into the feature test macros, maybe.